# R: obtaining subset of a column that matches a certain criteria

Tags: r, select

Let's say I have a table of data of all the students in a school. I want to look at family size of students who are male (1) and are at least considered "tall". How would I do this in R?

I only can seem to figure out how to get the column of family size of students, which would be `student_data$family_size`, but I can't figure out how to narrow it down any further.

```
   family_size  ...  gender ... height
1       6              1         very tall
2       3              0         tall
3       5              1         tall
4       4              1         tall
5      10              0         very short
6       2              1         average
```

So I would want:

```
     family_size
1       6
2       5
3       4
```

I'm not sure how the indexing would turn out, maybe it corresponds to the original indexing of the first table, but that's not as important.

Also, I'm not sure if what I've uploaded is a data frame or not, when I execute `typeof(student_data)`, it returns `"list"`

Comment: @akrun sorry, just edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset`.  It has the `subset` and `select` argument to pass a logical index to subset the rows and to select the columns based on the column index or name respectively.  In the OP's post, it is mentioned to extract the rows that have 'male' gender i.e. represented by 1 in the binary column.  So, `gender==1` gives a logical `TRUE/FALSE` by converting the 1 to TRUE and other values (0 here) to FALSE.  Another condition is to check which rows have the 'tall' substring in the 'height' column.  We use `grepl` to match the substring 'tall' in the 'height' column.  We couple both the conditions with `&`, and `select` the column 'family_size'.

```
subset(df1, gender==1 & grepl('tall', height), select= family_size)
#   family_size
#1           6
#3           5
#4           4
```

Or using `[` instead of `subset`.  The `[` is the recommended option to use inside functions.  But the default option is `drop=TRUE`.  So, if we are subsetting a single column, it might end up as `vector`.  To avoid that, we can use `drop=FALSE`.

```
df1[with(df1, gender==1 & grepl('tall', height)), 'family_size', drop=FALSE]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(family_size = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 2L), 
gender = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), height = c("very tall", "tall", "tall", 
"tall", "very short", "average")), .Names = c("family_size", 
"gender", "height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: the documentaiton says it's best to use `[`, because using `subset()` can have unintended consequences. Is there any way to do this with square brackets?

Comment: @AlanH Your are right.  It is better to use `[` inside functions.  Make sure to add `drop=FALSE` when you are selecting a single column.

Comment: @AlanH No, you don't need that.

Comment: Sorry, I have one last quesiton. I don't understand how `grepl` works. How does it know to include at least "tall" (meaning to also include "very tall" students)

Comment: @AlanH  We use the pattern `tall` to match all the strings that have the substring `tall` and `grepl` returns a logical index of TRUE/FALSE if the `tall` word is present or not.  Coupled with `gender==1`, we select the rows based on the TRUE/FALSE elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91232/discussion-between-alanh-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a column by indexing it with a column of True and False. First you generate a column of True and False

```
tallStudentsPositions <- (student_data$height == 'tall')
```

This gives you a column of True and False. The N th entry is True if the N th student has 'tall' in the height field. (Note that this test is case sensitive and doesn't care if you have 'Tall' or 'very tall' in the height field. You have to introduce appropriate tests for each entry you are interested in.)

Then you can access family size of all students that are designated 'tall' by

```
student_data$family_size[tallStudentsPositions]
```

You have introduce another similar step to filter out only the male students.